# Introduce a warning if no result of getstudents api call

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, callback

I just started using reactjs and api's .. When trying to add any new subject in react app you need to associate it with a teacher. however if you do not have a teacher assigned(first time user), the teacher slot is just disabled.

how do i Introduce a warning at top of modal if no result of the getteacher call.(that says "you dont have a teacher assigned.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `state` for this,

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       isTeacherAssigned:false //Initially false
    }
}
```

Then when you make a call to your API, and you get empty response to can set state,

```
fetch(url)
.then(response =>{
    return response.json();
})
.then(response =>{
    //check if response is empty
    if(responseEmpty){
       this.setState({isTeacherAssigned:false})
    }else{
       this.setState({isTeacherAssigned:true})
    }
})
```

In render,

```
{!this.state.isTeacherAssigned && <div>You dont have a teacher assigned..</div>}
```